# Approximating triple integrals over tiny regions

Tags: calculus

As a way of learning the divergence theorem, we have considered microscopic flux of a vector field through a tiny region.

Consider:

$$\iiint_D (\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2 +\partial_z^2)(u) dV$$

We don't know anything about u except that it is a function of (t,x,y,z).

I am told that if we make the region D very tiny, then we can approximate the integral above as :

$$(\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2 +\partial_z^2)(u) \cdot volume\space of D$$

Can someone explain why this is so? Is it something to do with the 2nd order partials being constants, or something? I'm having a hard time visualising

Thanks

Comment: You can write an integral $$\iiint_D f dV = \left( \frac{1}{|D|} \iiint_D f dV \right) |D|$$ where $|D|$ stands for the volume of $D$. The first term represents an average of $f$, which can be replaced by the value of $f$ if the region is small enough - a continuous function can't vary too much over a sufficiently small region. This is just a version of the fundamental theorem of calculus, really - taking $|D| \to 0$ corresponds to differentiating an integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, for a small region,
$$\int f \mathrm{d}V \approx f \int \mathrm{d}V=fV$$
If the function $f$ is "nice enough", because we can treat $f$ as a constant there.